# Is it acceptable to use global variables for "registering" functions in Python?

Tags: python, global-variables, python-decorators

It is common knowledge that global variables are always bad. But learning about python decorators, I find code snippets like this:

```
PLUGINS = dict()

def register(func):
    PLUGINS[func.__name__] = func
    return func

@register
def say_hello(name):
    return f"Hello {name}"

def get_function(func_name):
    return PLUGINS["func_name"]
```

I want to use decorators to register some functions, but I'm hesitant about why a global variable is used. It does seem efficient, but it feels wrong. Is it best practice to make an exception in this case? Or is there a better way?

Comment: This is fine. Some things are naturally global.

Comment: Global variables aren't bad, but they are often misused by new programmers. Everything that uses a global variable is in some sense coupled. But lots of things like function and class definitions are global to a module.In your case, if PLUGINS is applicable to the entire application, then its a good option for globals.